# There was an error performing the requested operation. Please try again or contact us for assistance

Tags: orocommerce

while performing operation on user, product or category we are getting this error. we don't have ssh access to clear cache. please let us know cause of error and also UI option to clear cache.

[image]

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: try clearing your cache, but could you try asking their support for assistance? thank you!

Comment: If you are the application administrator, check the var/logs/prod.log file for the error details or ask the developer to do so.

Comment: We are seeing this error for no obvious reason as well. Clearing cache does not resolve it. Nothing weird in the log file. No error seems to actually be occurring, the action being taken still completes, but that red message flashes.

Comment: we are not able view products or category, message display once we click on any link.